# Enumerate through a component's state in React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

so I wanted to have a component iterate through an object within it's state and pass the data down to it's child. My parent component looks basically like this:

```
class ListContainer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {"stuff": {
            "pie": ["bread", "apple"],
            "fries": ["potatoes", "oil"]
            }
        };

    render(){
        let rendArr = [];
        for(recipe in this.state.stuff){
            let newRecipe = <Child tableName={recipe} recipeData={this.state.stuff[recipe]} />;
            rendArr.push(newRecipe);
        }

        return(
            <div id="11"> I work
                {rendArr}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

However, I get an error saying that the "recipe" placeholder I used in the for loop isn't defined. I'm guessing I'm using the for loop here wrong with JSX, but I don't know the right way to iterate through an object. I know I could probably just convert it into an array of objects or something, but right now I'd like to understand why this for loop doesn't work in React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ReactJS`: typical practice is to [`render lists`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

[`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Destructuring Assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) can be combined to reach a convenient form.

See below for a practical example.

```js
// List.
class List extends React.Component {

  // State.
  state = {
    recipes: {
      pie: ['bread', 'apple'],
      fries: ['potatoes', 'oil']
    }
  }

  // Render.
  render = () => (
    <div id="11">
    
      <h1>Map</h1>
      {this.map()}
      
      <h1>For Loop</h1>
      {this.forLoop()}
      
    </div>
  )
  
  // Map.
  map = () => Object.entries(this.state.recipes).map(([name, recipe]) => <Recipe key={name} name={name} recipe={recipe}/>)
  
  // For Loop.
  forLoop = () => {
    const list = []
    for (let name in this.state.recipes) {
      const recipe = this.state.recipes[name]
      const line = <Recipe key={name} name={name} recipe={recipe}/>
      list.push(line)
    }
    return list
  }
}

// Recipe.
const Recipe = ({name, recipe}) => (
  <div>
    <h3 style={{textTransform: 'capitalize'}}>{name}</h3>
    {recipe.map(ingredient => <div>{ingredient}</div>)}
  </div>
)

ReactDOM.render(<List/>, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: After changing it to an array of objects and trying to iterate through it using a standard for(i=0...), which also didn't work, I did end up using the map function instead. The map function works, but I still don't understand why a standard for loop or a for...in loop doesn't work. What's the critical difference between for loops and Array.map?

Comment: `for loops` work too. `map()` is just more functional. I think your mistake might have been forgetting to declare your `recipe` iterator using `let`. See above for an example of each  @albert

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pushing component in an array, push the object and pull that in the render using map method:

```
render(){
        let rendArr = [];
        for(recipe in this.state.stuff){
            rendArr.push({tn: recipe, rd: this.state.stuff[recipe]});
        }
        return(
            <div id="11"> I work
                {
                 rendArr.map(el=> {
                   <Child tableName={el.tn} recipeData={el.rd} />
                 })
               }
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `map` instead of for..in loop:

```
render(){
    const rendArr = this.state.stuff.map((recipe, i) => <Child
        key={i}
        tableName={recipe}
        recipeData={recipe}
    />);

    return(
        <div id="11"> I work
            {rendArr}
        </div>
    );
}
```